# Prove that the distributions of $(\Sigma_{i=1}^n \xi_i) / (\Sigma_{i=1}^n \xi_i^2)^{1/2}$ converge weakly to $N(0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2,...$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables with $E \xi_1=0$ and $0<\sigma^2=\text{Var}(\xi_1) < \infty$. Prove that the distributions of $(\Sigma_{i=1}^n \xi_i) / (\Sigma_{i=1}^n \xi_i^2)^{1/2}$ converge weakly to $N(0,1) $distribution as $n \to \infty$.

My attempt: I divide both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n}\sigma$. Then I find the numerator converges to N(0,1) by central limit theorem. But how to do the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LLN on the denominator, and then the result follows by Slutky's theorem.

Comment: How to use LLN?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i^2\to \mathbb{E}[\xi_i^2]=\sigma^2$